# Is every integer a solution to the generalized pell-like equation

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

Is every integer a solution to a generalized Pell-like equation, like, can we find integer solutions to $ax^2-by^2=n$, $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{N}$ for any integer $n$?

Specifically, it is difficult to determine the existence to a particular Pell equation. But, I think any integer can satisfy an equation of the form $ax^2-by^2$, that is, any integer can be in the vector space of integer squares. Is this true? I think this has a lot to do with quadratic forms. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $a=n, x=1, b=0, y=1$?

Comment: @5xum so that was trivial! What if I require $a,b,x,y$ positive? Edited the post by the way

Comment: Yes. You can always pick an equation.    You can use this formula. 
  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: @individ that is the point I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: With $a=b=1$ you can get all the odd integers and all the doubly even integers. I'm pretty sure you can get the others with just a few more possibilities for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, I too thought of that. Just the difference of squares of integers differing by two would give you any even integer, I suppose?

Comment: @vidyarthi $a=n+1, x=1, b=1, y=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $a=n+1$ and $x=y=b=1$ gives you $$ax^2-by^2=(n+1)\cdot 1 - 1\cdot 1 = n$$

Answer (score 3):

1. If $n$ is not a power of $2$ then $n=2^k(2m+1) \space k \ge 0, m > 0$ so $n=2^k(m+1)^2 - 2^km^2$.
2. If $n$ is a power of $4$ then $n = 2^{2k} = (2^{k+1})^2 - 3(2^k)^2$.
3. If $n$ is a power of $2$ but not a power of $4$ then $n=2^{2k+1} = (2^{k+1})^2 - 2(2^k)^2$.